# How to load database configuration from preferences in eclipse e4 rcp?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I am trying to load and use my database configuration from preferences as suggested [here](http://blog.vogella.com/2013/07/19/inject-your-jpa-entitymanager-into-an-eclipse-rcp-application-guest-post-by-nepomuk-seiler/) using `properties = {...}` approach, but it is not working.

I get the following exception:

```
WARNING: EMFProxy invocation on method isOpen failed:  Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20130815-a4708b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: URL was not specified
```

The problem persists even if I hard code the values in `properties` using `value=...`. It somehow does not read the `properties`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! I wanted the `PersistenceUnitProperties.JDBC_DRIVER` to be static so I left it in the `persistence.xml` and did not add it programmatically. The problem was fixed when I removed it from persistence.xml and set it also programmatically.